# Parsing an XML document using LINQ (sample code inside)

Tags: c#, xml

I am a beginner learning to program in C#, so please be patient.  I have a fairly complex XML structure that I am working:

```
<Tab name ="Hospital">
  <section name="billing" id="22-78" author="James B. Moore" ID="87329874">
  </section>
</Tab>
<Tab name ="Insurance">
  <section name="billing" id="22-90" author="Sarah B. Patterson" ID="234546">
  </section>
</Tab>
<Tab name ="Billing">
  <section name="billing" id="22-96" author="Oli Ward" ID="8979">
  </section>
</Tab>
```

I have the following code:

```
//Method to get Tab Details
private static void GetTab(XDocument oXDocument, string p_Descendant, string p_Attribute)
{
    //Get Section List
    IEnumerable<XElement> rows = 
        from row in oXDocument.Descendants(p_Descendant) 
        select row;

    foreach (XElement xEle in rows)
    {
        IEnumerable<XAttribute> attList = 
            from att in xEle.DescendantsAndSelf().Attributes()
            select att;

        Console.WriteLine("Tab: " + (string)xEle.Attribute(p_Attribute));

        //Get Section Names
        string s_descendant = "section";
        string s_Attribute = "name";

        GetDetails(oXDocument, s_descendant, s_Attribute);
    }
}

//Method to get Section Details
private static void GetDetails(XDocument oXDocument, string p_Descendant, string p_Attribute)
{
    //Get Section List
    IEnumerable<XElement> rows = 
        from row in oXDocument.Descendants(p_Descendant)
        select row;


    foreach (XElement xEle in rows)
    {
        IEnumerable<XAttribute> attList = 
            from att in xEle.DescendantsAndSelf().Attributes()
            select att;

        Console.WriteLine("Section: " + (string)xEle.Attribute(p_Attribute));
    }
}
```

I think I am approaching this incorrectly. My logic seems to be; get the Tab Details, call another method which gets the attribute values, but this means I will have to create a method for every attribute value. Does anyone know of a better way?

I did the above my reading some MSDN documents and Youtube videos.

**Edit: (Sorry) what I am trying to achieve is a console output like the following:**

```
Tab: Hospital
  Section: Billing
    Values: id: 22-78, author: James B. Moore, ID: 87329874
Tab: Insurance
  Section: Billing
    Values: id: 22-90, author: Sara B. Patterson, ID: 234546
```

I am trying to loop through the XML and every instance of a Tab Element, I want to format to console like above.

I hope that is clear. Sorry about my English.

Comment: You didn't clearly stated what you want to achieve

Comment: Your question isn't very clear to me, what do mean with "I will have to create a method for every attribute value" for example?

Comment: Read up on DRY principles; the structures are all the same, so you can have one method that parses the structure based on a given parameter, the tab section name, and gets the id, author, and ID. Use an enum of the different section names to ensure safety.

Answer (score 0):

This code should achieve the output you presented

```
var xe = XDocument.Parse(Xml);

foreach (var tab in xe.Descendants("Tab"))
{
    var tabName = tab.Attribute("name").Value;
    var sectionName = tab.Element("section").Attribute("name").Value;
    var sectionValues = tab.Element("section").Attributes()
        .Where(x => x.Name != "name")
        .Select(x => string.Format("{0}: {1}", x.Name, x.Value));

    Console.WriteLine("Tab: {0}\n\tSection: {1}\n\t\tValues: {2}", tabName, sectionName, string.Join(", ", sectionValues));
}
```

It would look a lot nicer with C# 6.0 string interpolation but I didn't wont to assume you are using VS2015.